# roxygen2 (Version 5.0) incorrectly creates documentation when #' occurs inside function

Tags: r, roxygen2

Consider the following R function definition, to be documented using roxygen2 (version >=5.0)

```
#' @title Test Bug
#' @author Daniel Egan
#' @param x  
#' @return Nothing
#' @export
#' @examples
#' testFun(x)


testFun <- function(x){

  #' Warning1'
  return(TRUE)
}
```

When using devtools::document() to document this, it produces the following error:

> Warning messages:
>   1: @examples [TestFun.R#8]: mismatched braces or quotes

Note that there are DEFINITELY no mismatched braces or quotes in the "examples" section. What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a bug report to send to github. Workaround: don't do it! Put a space after your pound sign.

Comment: It's not a bug. Just don't do it.

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/428

Answer (score 8):

This is due to recent changes in the `roxygen2` package. From the [NEWS](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/blob/master/NEWS.md#minor-features-and-bug-fixes):

> The contents of documented functions are now also parsed for roxygen comments. This allows, e.g., documenting a parameter's type close to where this type is checked, or documenting implementation details close to the source, and simplifies future extensions such as the documentation of R6 classes.

This means that any roxygen-style comments *inside code blocks* will be parsed. If your package's code contains such comments inside functions, you probably want to substitute them with plain comments, i.e., replace `#'` by `#`. After this one-time change, simply don't use roxygen-style comments in code blocks anymore, unless intended.

The following command line (requires `sed`) substitutes all space-indented roxygen-style comments with plain comments in all files in the `R/` subdirectory of the current directory:

```
sed -r -i"" "s/( +#)'/\1/" R/*
```

Adapt it to your needs.

Comment: It would be great to have an example here, documenting R6 classes this way sounds cool!